# How to make Global var changeable by text input

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck at this point, I want to make a multiplication table, so when I tried to make a number of Columns changeable, my mind stuck, the thing is, I want to create an input text for a variable (n) like in the code, I made the var n fixed in 15, I want to make an option in HTML to change the var n by  
 ?!
I tried to do a new function named NumberColumn() and it doesn't work, please help!
javascript:

```
var n=15;
LigneX(n);
LigneY(n);
GenerateTableau(n);

function NumberColumn()
{
    var n;
    n = document.getElementById("txtnbr").value;
    return n;
}

function LigneX()
{
    var tt="<tr>";
    tt=tt+"<td>X</td>";
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        tt = tt+"<td class='orange'>"+i+"</td>";
    }
    tt = tt+"</tr>";
    return tt;
}

function LigneY(L)
{
    var m =0;
    var k=0;
    var tt ="<tr>";
    var cc = "white";
    tt = tt+"<td class='orange'>"+L+"</td>";
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        m = L * i ;
        k=(n/2)+0.5;

        if( i === L)
        {
            cc = 'yellow';

            if (i === k)   
                {cc = 'red';}
        }
        else
        {
            if((i + L)-1 === n)
                { cc = 'green'}
                else{ cc = 'white'}
        }

        tt = tt +"<td class='"+cc+"'>"+m+"</td>";
    }

    tt =tt+"</tr>";
    return tt;
}

function GenerateTableau()
{


    var tt = "<table class='myTable'>";
    tt = tt + LigneX();
    for(l =1;l<=n;l++)
    {
        tt=tt+LigneY(l);
    }
    tt=tt+"</table>";
    document.getElementById("divTableau").innerHTML=tt;
}
```

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tableau Multiplication</title>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exerice Tableau de Multiplication</h1>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="txtnbr"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Generate Tableau" onclick="GenerateTableau()"/>
    <div id="divTableau">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an event listener to your button and validate that the user has provided a valid size.
I wrote a small script that encapsulates the behavior and it will let you scale your app easly.

```js
function ResizeableTable(maxSize) {
  var size = maxSize || 10;
  var root = null;
  var body = null;
  var control = null;
  
  function init() {
    root = document.createElement('div');
    
    body = document.createElement('tbody');
    control = document.createElement('input');
    
    control.type = 'range';
    control.max = size;
    control.min = 1;
    control.value = size;
    
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var controlContainer = document.createElement('div');
    
    controlContainer.appendChild(control);
    
    rerender();
    table.appendChild(body);
    root.appendChild(controlContainer);
    root.appendChild(table);
  }
  
  function attachListeners() {
    control.addEventListener('change', resize);
  }
  
  function rerender() {
    body.innerHTML = '';
    var row;
    var cell;
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < (size + 1); i++) {
      row = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < (size + 1); j++) {
        result = i * j;  
        cell = document.createElement('td');
        
        cell.innerText = (
          result === 0
          ? 'x'
          : result
        );
      
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }
      body.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
  
  function resize() {
    var newSize = Number.parseInt(control.value);
    if (size === newSize) { return; }
    size = newSize;
    rerender();
  }
  
  function mount(node) {
    node.appendChild(root);
  }
  
  init();
  attachListeners();
  
  return {
    mount: mount
  }
}


var table = ResizeableTable(15);
table.mount(document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow , that is a high level for me , a lot of thing to processor , thanks for the answer bro